# Interpret string as number; reencode it into another base

Tags: javascript, radix

Consider the concept of a "number alphabet"; a "number alphabet" is a `String` where each character of the `String` represents a valid digit that can be used to represent a number. The overall length of the `String` represents the base of that specific "number alphabet". The order of the characters in the `String` represents the successive values of each character. A character may not repeat throughout the "number alphabet".

For example, the `String` `'0123456789'` represents typical decimal numbers; any `String` whose characters are all found within `'0123456789'` is able to be interpreted as a decimal value. Specifically, we should be able to say `interpret('0123456789', '127') === 127`. This `interpret` function takes a "number alphabet" and a value within that "number alphabet", and returns the numeric value.

It's not too hard to implement `interpret`:

```js
const interpret = (alphabet, str) => {
  
  let sum = 0;
  const base = alphabet.length;
  const maxInd = str.length - 1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= maxInd; i++) {
    
    // Simple to get value of char within alphabet - I know this is O(m * n) but not
    // concerned about that here
    const chrVal = alphabet.indexOf(str[i]);
    
    // Earlier characters count for more, same as how in the number 4278 the 4 represents
    // 4000, larger than the 2 which is 200, larger than the 7 which is 70, etc.
    const placeInd = maxInd - i;
    
    // The "place" value in `str`, same as how in the number 4278 the 4 is 1000s, 2 is
    // 100s, 7 is 10s, etc.
    const placeVal = base ** placeInd;
        
    // Overall the value contributed by this "place" in `str` is `placeVal` times the
    // value of the character in `str` at this place
    sum += placeVal * chrVal;
    
  }
  return sum;
  
};

const tests = [
  { alpha: '0123456789', str: '20' },
  { alpha: '0123456789', str: '119992' },
  { alpha: '0123456789', str: '0000119992' },
  { alpha: '0123456789abcdef', str: 'ff' },
  { alpha: '0123456789abcdef', str: 'beef' },
  { alpha: '0123456789abcdef', str: 'deadbeef' },
  { alpha: '0123456789abcdef', str: 'a0' },
  { alpha: '01', str: '100111100' },
  { alpha: '-+', str: '+--++++--' },
  { alpha: '~!@#', str: '@#!#' }, // Now there's no reason we can't do this
];
for (const test of tests) console.log(`interpret('${test.alpha}', '${test.str}') = ${interpret(test.alpha, test.str)}`);
```

My main goal, however, is to translate a string from any arbitrary alphabet to any other; I am calling this task **`reinterpret`** and here is an example usage:

```
reinterpret('0123456789', '01', '1337') === '10100111001'
```

In this case "0123456789" is given as the source alphabet and "01" as the target alphabet; the string `'1337'` represents `1337` in the source alphabet, and `reinterpret` returns `'10100111001'`, representing the same value in the target alphabet.

You'd think implementating `reinterpret` would be easy as we can easily write a function which reverses `interpret` (call it `uninterpret`) and then simply implement as:

```
reinterpret = (srcAlpha, trgAlpha, str) => uninterpret(trgAlpha, interpret(srcAlpha, str));
```

There is a problem, though. Here is an `uninterpret` implementation; note that it reverses the results from `interpret`:

```js
const logBaseHandleLikelyIntegers = (base, num) => {
  const eps = 0.000000000000005;
  const rough = Math.log(num) / Math.log(base); // May have a floating point error
  
  // Try to correct floating point error when it looks like it should be an integer
  if (Math.floor(rough + eps) > rough) return Math.floor(rough) + 1;
  if (Math.ceil( rough - eps) < rough) return Math.ceil(rough) - 1;
  
  return rough;
};

const uninterpret = (alpha, num) => {
  
  const base = alpha.length;
    
  // Use log where the base is the alphabet length to determine number of chars needed
  const digitsNeeded = Math.floor(logBaseHandleLikelyIntegers(base, num) + 1);
    
  let str = '';
  for (let p = digitsNeeded - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
    const pow = Math.pow(base, p);
    const div = Math.floor(num / pow);
    str += alpha[div];
    num -= pow * div;
  }
  
  return str;
  
};

const tests = [
  { alpha: '0123456789', num: 20 },
  { alpha: '0123456789', num: 119992 },
  { alpha: '0123456789abcdef', num: 255 },
  { alpha: '0123456789abcdef', num: 48879 },
  { alpha: '0123456789abcdef', num: 3735928559 },
  { alpha: '0123456789abcdef', num: 160 },
  { alpha: '01', num: 316 },
  { alpha: '-+', num: 316 },
  { alpha: '~!@#', num: 183 }, // Now there's no reason we can't do this
  { alpha: '0123456789', num: 1000 }, // Cases like this require an integer log result and necessitate the helper function
];
for (const test of tests) console.log(`uninterpret('${test.alpha}', '${test.num}') = ${uninterpret(test.alpha, test.num)}`);
```

Now here is a `reinterpret` implementation using `interpret` and `uninterpret`:

```js
const logBaseHandleLikelyIntegers = (base, num) => {
  const eps = 0.000000000000005;
  const rough = Math.log(num) / Math.log(base); // May have a floating point error
  
  // Try to correct floating point error when it looks like it should be an integer
  if (Math.floor(rough + eps) > rough) return Math.floor(rough) + 1;
  if (Math.ceil( rough - eps) < rough) return Math.ceil(rough) - 1;
  
  return rough;
};

const interpret = (alphabet, str) => {
  
  let sum = 0;
  const base = alphabet.length;
  const maxInd = str.length - 1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= maxInd; i++) {
    
    // Simple to get value of char within alphabet - I know this is O(m * n) but not
    // concerned about that here
    const chrVal = alphabet.indexOf(str[i]);
    
    // Earlier characters count for more, same as how in the number 4278 the 4 represents
    // 4000, larger than the 2 which is 200, larger than the 7 which is 70, etc.
    const placeInd = maxInd - i;
    
    // The "place" value in `str`, same as how in the number 4278 the 4 is 1000s, 2 is
    // 100s, 7 is 10s, etc.
    const placeVal = base ** placeInd;
        
    // Overall the value contributed by this "place" in `str` is `placeVal` times the
    // value of the character in `str` at this place
    sum += placeVal * chrVal;
    
  }
  return sum;
  
};
const uninterpret = (alpha, num) => {
  
  const base = alpha.length;
    
  // Use log where the base is the alphabet length to determine number of chars needed
  const digitsNeeded = Math.floor(logBaseHandleLikelyIntegers(base, num) + 1);
    
  let str = '';
  for (let p = digitsNeeded - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
    const pow = Math.pow(base, p);
    const div = Math.floor(num / pow);
    str += alpha[div];
    num -= pow * div;
  }
  
  return str;
  
};
const reinterpret = (srcAlpha, trgAlpha, str) => uninterpret(trgAlpha, interpret(srcAlpha, str));

const reinterpretTest = (src, trg, str) => {
  console.log(`Reinterpret the value "${str}" in alphabet "${src}", under alphabet "${trg}":`);
  console.log(`Result: ${reinterpret(src, trg, str)}`);
};

console.log('Base 10 -> base 2 test:');
reinterpretTest('0123456789', '01', '32');

console.log('\nBase 10 -> base 16 tests:');
reinterpretTest('0123456789', '0123456789abcdef', '1287589');
reinterpretTest('0123456789', '0123456789abcdef', '87771287589933381');
reinterpretTest('0123456789', '0123456789abcdef', '87771287589933382');
```

Run the above code and... uh oh, two different strings `'87771287589933381'` and `'87771287589933382'` were interpreted to the same value, `'137d3856246d140'`. Why? Because these strings are large, and the numbers in `uninterpret` are getting so large they are losing precision.

**How can I implement `reinterpret` to work on inputs of arbitrary sizes?** I think it's tricky; I think exponentiation needs to be avoided somehow.

I'm not at all asking about the maximum size/precision of `Number`; I'm looking to circumvent a limitation that exists in my current code as a result of that maximum precision.

Comment: Can you use `BigNumber`? It supports arbitrary length integers.

Comment: *`BigInt` @Barmar

Comment: The closure due to duplicate is completely off-base lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

```js
const interpret = (alphabet, str) => {
  
  let sum = 0n;
  const base = alphabet.length;
  const maxInd = str.length - 1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= maxInd; i++) {
    
    // Simple to get value of char within alphabet - I know this is O(m * n) but not
    // concerned about that here
    const chrVal = alphabet.indexOf(str[i]);
    
    // Earlier characters count for more, same as how in the number 4278 the 4 represents
    // 4000, larger than the 2 which is 200, larger than the 7 which is 70, etc.
    const placeInd = maxInd - i;
    
    // The "place" value in `str`, same as how in the number 4278 the 4 is 1000s, 2 is
    // 100s, 7 is 10s, etc.
    const placeVal = BigInt(base) ** BigInt(placeInd);
        
    // Overall the value contributed by this "place" in `str` is `placeVal` times the
    // value of the character in `str` at this place
    sum += placeVal * BigInt(chrVal);
    
  }
  return sum;
  
};
const uninterpret = (alpha, num) => {
  
  const base = BigInt(alpha.length);
  const digits = [];

  while (num) {
    digits.push(alpha[num % base]);
    num /= base;
  }
  
  return digits.reverse().join("");
  
};
const reinterpret = (srcAlpha, trgAlpha, str) => uninterpret(trgAlpha, interpret(srcAlpha, str));

const reinterpretTest = (src, trg, str) => {
  console.log(`Reinterpret the value "${str}" in alphabet "${src}", under alphabet "${trg}":`);
  console.log(`Result: ${reinterpret(src, trg, str)}`);
};

console.log('Base 10 -> base 2 test:');
reinterpretTest('0123456789', '01', '32');

console.log('\nBase 10 -> base 16 tests:');
reinterpretTest('0123456789', '0123456789abcdef', '1287589');
reinterpretTest('0123456789', '0123456789abcdef', '87771287589933381');
reinterpretTest('0123456789', '0123456789abcdef', '87771287589933382');
```

N.b. `uninterpret(alpha, 0n) === ""`

Comment: Awesome, a straightforward fix!